# In .net client detect signalr Hub server crash

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to inform to client of server crash i.e. singnalr hub crash and 
call my method  in .net client which try to reconnect after 10 secs , 
How to know if server crashed in my .net client

Comment: after server craches, the client ondisconnected event fires after 30+ seconds.

Comment: I used closed event of HubConnection  , this solved my problem